# Specify auto login for a specific tty in rhel 6.5

Tags: linux

Hi everyone I have a problem in auto login for only a specific (say tty1) tty. I want to startx in tty 1 for that I have modify `/etc/init/tty.conf` file lik this :
`exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin username  $TTY`  and  then modified `/home/.bash_profile`   in home directory like

```
If [[-z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty)= /dev/tty1 ]]; then
 startx
fi
```

And every time it login and startx automatically but the problem is I can switch to other tty which are already logged in( auto login in evey tty1 to tty 6) , autually I want auto log in this nly for tty1 and for other tty we have to enter user name and password. I have tried to modify in in `/etc/init/tty.conf` like

```
exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin username /dev/tty1
exec /sbin/mingetty  /dev/tty2
exec /sbin/mingetty  /dev/tty3 like this to tty 6
```

But problem is that after booting screen goes blanks; my operating system is RHEL 6.5